# RegEx to match characters from list except if characters another list are present

Tags: php, regex, pcre

I'm trying to build a regex to validate passwords in my application.

This is PCRE (php).

My regex so far looks like this

```
/^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[!@#\$%\^&\*\(\)_\+\-\=\[\]\{\}\|'])(?=.*[^\\\/])(?=.{8,20})/
```

And my criteria are the following

```
minimum length:            8
maximum length:            20
require special character: true
require uppercase:         true
require lowercase:         true
require number:            true
special character set:     !@#$%^&*()_+-=[]{}|'
excluded character set:    \/
```

Everything works but the excluded character set. The idea is the password must not contain any of the characters specified in that list.

Thanks for the help

Comment: Replace `(?=.*[^\\\/])` with `(?!.*\/)`. Or, remove this lookahead, and replace `.{8,20}` with `[^\/]{8,20}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
/^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[!@#$%^&*()_\-+=[\]{}|'])[^\/]{8,20}$/
```

See [proof](https://regex101.com/r/OZdqb5/1)

Alternative:

```
/^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[!@#$%^&*()_\-+=[\]{}|'])[A-Za-z0-9!@#$%^&*()_+\-=[\]{}|']{8,20}$/
```

See [another proof](https://regex101.com/r/OZdqb5/2)

```
minimum length:            8                    <= {8,20}
maximum length:            20                   <= {8,20}
require special character: true                 <= (?=.*[!@#$%^&*()_\-+=[\]{}|'])
require uppercase:         true                 <= (?=.*[A-Z])
require lowercase:         true                 <= (?=.*[a-z])
require number:            true                 <= (?=.*[0-9])
special character set:     !@#$%^&*()_+-=[]{}|' <= [^\/]
excluded character set:    \/                   <= [^\/]
```

Comment: Your "alternative" is different from your first pattern. In the first pattern, `[^/]` allows absolutely everything that is not a slash (including control characters, white characters, missing punctuation characters, and the extended ascii part `\x80-\xFF`), when the "alternative" pattern limits the possible characters to the require characters.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte That is why I wrote "alternative" and not "equivalent".